# Restrict regex for phone number prefixes to two numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have a regular expression validation for a phone number prefix like this:

> It should start with a `+` sign and followed by two digits e.g.: `+91`

My code is

```js
$(function() {
  $('#textId').on('input', function() {
    console.log($(this).val())

    var regex = /^\+(?:[\d]*)$/;
    console.log($(this).val())
    var res = regex.test($(this).val());
    $('#result').text(regex.test($(this).val()))
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="textId" name="" />

<div id="result">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm2hS/3438/)

It is validating the `+` sign in the starting, followed by any number of digits. I need to restrict it to two digits. Any help?

Comment: `/^\+\d{2}$/` is the minimum regex you need. No need for a non-capturing group or a character class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just specify `{2}` instead of `*`:

```
var regex = /^\+(?:[\d]{2})$/ ;
//                     ^^^
```

`{n}` is a quantifier to indicate that you want the specified pattern to be matched exactly `n` times. In this case, then, `[\d]{2}` means: match exactly 2 digits.

You can test it in a fork of your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/a2j0qfvx/

Comment: Thanks,That worked.When i press + it is showing false at the start,how can solve that? like +9 is showing false

Comment: @Gopesh well, the regex is matching `+` followed by two digits, so `+` alone does not match. Isn't this the behaviour you desire?

Comment: what iam trying to acheive is to prevent the user to type other than a + sign in the start and two digits

Comment: @Gopesh then this is fine: it won't allow anything else than `+dd`. If you needed to track the way the user is typing, you may want to add some kind of comment above on the form _do start your phone with + followed by two digits_.

Comment: Perhaps `^\+\d{2}$` is a shorter version, since there dont seem to be the need for `(?:)` non capturing group and the `[]` single character match brackets. :)

Comment: @SWLim that is a good point. Since `[ ]` is used to group several characters and we just use one, `\d`, it is superfluous. Also, `(?:)` is not needed at all. So yes, I agree on your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace your `*` with a `{2}`

```
^\+(?:[\d]{2})$
```

[working demo](http://regexr.com/3dp7v)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
var regex = /^\+(?:[\d]{2})$/
```

We can specify the number of character in curly braces